# How do I stream video from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to stream video directly from the iPhone? Is there any undocumented way to do it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

With iOS4 you can gain access to the raw video frames via AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

Once you have the frames, its up to you to compress them, package them up, and send them wherever they need to go.