# stream video from iPhone to media server

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

What are the possible best ways to stream video from iPhone to media server.

Which server is best for this purpose?

What guidelines should I follow to achieve this task?

Comment: Streaming how? Over Wi-Fi or 3G or over USB?

Comment: I think if you are streaming to the media server it obviously will be through wi-fi, isn't it ?

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: My task is just to stream the audio/video to the media server (over the internet), What steps does this task requires to acomplish... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206478/how-do-i-stream-video-from-the-iphone

Comment: Do you want to live stream or just stream ?
The easiest way is to use ffmpeg as the current SDK won't allow you to stream